# COUNTIFS Statement Between Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a report I am creating that sifts through a lot of Data, I have created a COUNTIFS statement that does what I want, but I am having trouble with the dates.

I am trying to find the number of items between 2 weeks and 4 weeks
I have used `TODAY` to write the formula, but I want to be able to select cell `K2` instead and return the same information, where `K2` = start date required

This is the current statement:

```
=COUNTIFS(NCR_DATA!R:R,">="&TODAY()-"14",NCR_DATA!R:R,"<="&TODAY()-"28",NCR_DATA!M:M,"*Supervisor*",NCR_DATA!D:D,"ISBL",NCR_DATA!G:G,"Open")
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need the cell values outside the quotes so you concatenate with an & with the boolean expression.

If Supervisor is in a cell you could just replace "Supervisor" with K4

Try

> =COUNTIFS(NCR_DATA!R:R,">="&K2,NCR_DATA!R:R,"<="&K3,NCR_DATA!M:M,"Supervisor",NCR_DATA!D:D,"ISBL",NCR_DATA!G:G,"Open")

Comment: removing quotes from days returns the same as leaving them in...  no change really, and either way returns the information.  but I need to be able to specify a date in the statement by putting the required date into a cell (K2) intead of using '&TODAY()-14' I want to use K2-14 but am unsure how to work this into the statement

Comment: Sorry I didn't read it correctly I have updated the answer with the assumption that K2 is your start date and K3 is your end data

Comment: this works great thank you,   I did not have an end date due to the -number in the formula.  but I can add it in.  Thanks Again

Comment: If it works you can select the answer as the correct answer to show people it's been solved.  Cheers.